# SpringBoot Actuator to obtain http.server.requests having PathVariable

Tags: spring-boot

We have enabled actuator for for Spring Application
I have two Rest Services in my Controller

1. myAPI with no Parameters
2. myParamAPI with myParam--> String Parameter (PathVariable)

Now if I use
http://localhost.com:8449/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/myAPI
it shows the statistics

However if I use
[http://localhost.com:8449/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/myParamAPI/{myParam}](http://localhost.com:8449/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/myParamAPI/%7BmyParam%7D)
it doesn't show up

Actuator docs, couldn't find anything for it